# Commulative patches for oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Oracle recently released new version of Application Express 5.1.2 Patch #: 25786300.

After some research I found out that I cannot download this patch without having support account of oracle which requires **Support Identifier** to get registered does that means that patches are not free and we have to purchase a service to get patches for oracle apex?

Comment: Yes, patches are not free. Oracle is a commercial organisation and licenses its products. In fact it makes most of its profit from Support contracts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about licensing not programming

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you must have a support contract for incremental patches.

You can, however, download the complete patched 5.1.2 version from Oracle and install it.